# Javascript passing variable from function to function

Tags: javascript, function

How do i pass **var rating** and **var itervalue** into my window.location.replace? i get new rating variable from function updateRating() and when i click hireraccept, it assigns a new itervalue variable which i wish to pass them both into the "proceed" button into the window.location.replace url. any idea?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var rating =  0;
   var itervalue = 0;

   $(".hireraccept").click(function(){
                $('.jRating').jRating();
                $("#dialog-rate").dialog("open");
                var itervalue = $(this).attr("value");


                return false

            });


            $("#dialog-rate").dialog({

                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 200,        
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Proceed": function(){

                        window.location.replace("{{ domain_url }}/workroom/accept/" + itervalue +"/" + rating);
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }

                }


            });

  });
 </script>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function updateRating(rate,proceed){
      goodtogo = proceed;

      rating = rate;

} 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your iterval declared globally, but then redeclare it locally. Remove the var declaration from your click handler and it will overwrite the global value, which you can then use in your dialog opening options.

// edit
Change this

```
var itervalue = $(this).attr("value");
```

to this, and that should work

```
itervalue = $(this).attr("value");
```

Comment: but i need to grab the click handler's itervalue value...how can i remove it? i need it exactly the opposite of what you are saying. i need the local variable to overwrite the global value so that another function can access it?

Comment: In the click handler you posted you're only setting the value for itervalue not rating.

Comment: Nope, my window.location.replace which is inside my proceed button has a rating & itervalue variable. So i need that too

Comment: I must be missing something in your code. Your dialog does not set the rating either. Unless you're setting rating somewhere else I don't see how it's being set anywhere.

Comment: Wups, missed that - When do you call that function?

Comment: i call it when i click my rating plugin. i will pass the rate variable from the plugin into this updateRating function then i wanna pass it to the "proceed" function...they are not in the same script tag > will it affect the passing even if i declare a global variable outside the updateRating() function?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are in the same script tag. You have to call the updateRating function (with the correct parameters) before you open the dialog. That's the only thing that I can think of that's going wrong. Are there any warnings or errors in your Inspector/Firebug?